# How to watch a Windows Media Streaming in OS X 10.9.2

Tags: safari, plugins, video

I'm trying to watch a live streaming using the Windows Media plugin but it's appears to be impossible.

The old Flip4Mac free software appears to be paid now and I was not able to find any free and/or opensource alternative.

There's a way to watch WMV Streaming in the browser itself in OS X Mavericks?

Comment: I found Flip4Mac 3 on MacUpdate and it says it is compatible with Mavericks: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17787/flip4mac-wmv-player

Comment: Give the the link to the video and I will try it.

Comment: The link is here: http://video.rnp.br/portal/transmission.action?idItem=21525